# Joomla 3 menu item URL appened

Tags: url, joomla, menu, append, joomla3.0

Joomla version 3 menu item has a field called "Note" which is primarily used to display notes in the administrator backend.

I have populated "note" field with something like "&City=4&County=0" Now I want to append this in front of the Link URL.  Link URL is none editable field which is automatically populated based on article selected so I cannot edit or type in it manually.

Normal URL based upon selection of the article looks like something this:

```
index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=10
```

Now I want to append the note field in front of this URL so the URL would look like:

```
index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=10&City=4&County=0
```

Here is the screenshot:

[image]
<sub>(source: [linkbank.co.uk](http://www.linkbank.co.uk/menu.png))</sub>

Comment: I know it is possible to make a extension in joomla, but I am not a programmer and looking for the easiest method to accomplish this, and I couldn't think anything simpler than this?

Comment: there might be another method to append this information infront of the URL which I may not be aware of, I am desperate to get this fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a new view, just copy components/com_content/views/article to cityarticle or something meaningful, then edit the default.xml you find in its subfolder ./tmpl, change the name so you can identify it and add the fields city and county to the

on line 16 roughly, those will appear when you create a new menu item (on the right) so you can set them, and will be passed on as get requests.

Choose the appropriate field type and read the docs here: 
http://docs.joomla.org/Standard_form_field_and_parameter_types

Comment: You know what, I cannot resist to tell you that you are a super star, you have save my time from being wasted. It works. But there is another problem know. It works fine if the SEF is not enabled and if I enable SEF it does not work. With SEF option enabled I parameters are not passed and it breaks everything. Any ideas?

Comment: Riccardo, please help me fix this SEF URL issue. I will be very happy if I can get rid of this problem. With SEF enabled I get SQL error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1" but when I disable the SEF URL everything works as expected. Not sure what shall I do with this? Please help!

Comment: Did you add a menu item pointing to the new view, or you're just calling it typing the url? because unless you set a menu item, Joomla SEF router won't know what to call. You can set it in a hidden menu, it's not necessary that you show it.

Comment: I have managed to fix this by using third party plugin JoomSEF by Artio.